# civibuild create is not working/frozen

Tags: drupal, extension, civibuild

[image]

is there any alternative? that I can use to install Drupal+CiviCRM development environment. taking too long it(in screenshot) took 2 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks my Problem has been solved!
I have used this technique to solve this Problem:

I wanted to use `./bin/setup.sh -g`  this command to generate sql and DAO, for that what I did is:

Just downloaded [civicrm-core](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core) from GitHub and then patched with an installation of CiviCRM drupal module.

**How I did patch this: (in Ubuntu)**

I have just mixed/merged civicrm-core and CiviCRM's drupal module in one directory.

and then I have just configured civicrm-core/bin/setup.conf by copying setup.conf.txt with my real installation of CiviCRM database information.

that's it configuration success.

now I can use `./bin/setup.sh -g` while i am on civicrm-core-master directory.

to generate sql and DAO please read **carefully carefully** every step from here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-entity

If you are having any difficulties please comment down below, I will be glad to help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might try a CiviBuild in Docker. See https://github.com/michaelmcandrew/civicrm-buildkit-docker for the link and how to install it.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem has been solved and I have switched to Linux(Ubuntu); it might help others...

Answer (score 0):

I use FTP and upload all the files and then run the installer.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/installing-drupal-7/step-1-download-and-extract-drupal

I do the same with CiviCRM

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/drupal7/

Comment: Actually, i'm trying to create Entity using command line and generating sql for them as said here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-entity command i need to run is: <civiroot>/bin/setup.sh -g to generate sql

Comment: The page says:
Caution
This functionality is considered "experimental and incomplete".

Comment: How you create proper working Entity? can you give me some instruction or any tutorial?